# How to set python executable path in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

I've been using Python only a couple years, primarily through Jupyter notebooks and Spyder, which came with Anaconda. I'm starting to use IDLE some and have problems with loading packages. I'm wondering if the issue stems from the fact I have different Python executables, one used by Jupyter/Spyder and the other by IDLE.

In IDLE, I typed

```
 import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

which resulted in

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

In both Spyder and in a Jupyter notebook, I also typed

```
 import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

which resulted in

```
/Users/fishbacp/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Spyder indicates it's using Python 3.7 as well.

While I've installed numpy and a plethora of packages for use in Spyder/Jupyter, no such packages can currently be imported within the IDLE shell. A simple "ModuleNotFoundError" results. Because I have so many packages already installed, I'd rather not re-install them for use in IDLE.

Is there a simple way for me to configure IDLE so that it uses the 3.7 located in /Users/fishbacp/anaconda3/bin/python?

If it's relevant, my machine is a Mac running Catalina 10.15.4.

Comment: maybe virtual environment would be good for you

Comment: Make use of `venv`.  Or, set up a shortcut to run `/Users/fishbacp/anaconda3/bin/python -m idlelib.idle`. It would not be advisable to change your default IDLE to point to a virtual env executable.  I'm not an anaconda user but IIRC it's kinda like a venv itself already? Doesn't it come with an interactive shell?

Comment: Anaconda comes with Spyder, which is an IDE also having an interactive shell. For some reason, I'm having problems using tkinter (GUI development package) in Spyder, issues I don't have in IDLE, and I also like the cleaner look of IDLE. 

I'm not sure how to set up the shortcut you describe?

Answer (score 1):

IDLE is run by whatever python you explicitly or implicitly ask to run IDLE.  The icon installed by the python.org installer at some point executes something like

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -m idlelib
```

In Terminal, you could execute

```
/Users/fishbacp/anaconda3/bin/python -m idlelib
```

However, there might be issues with the version of tcl/tk associated with that python, if different, especially on Catalina. See IDLE's Help => About IDLE for the tk x.y.z version.

You may be better off with 3.8.2 (or soon, 3.8.3).