# tkinter does not function correctly in Spyder

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I'm trying to use tkinter in Spyder 3.32 running python 3.7. I have a simple script to accept two numbers and print their sum:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Sum Calculator")
window.geometry('600x300')
lbl1 = Label(window, text="First Number")
lbl1.grid(row=0,column=0)
txt1 = Entry(window,width=10) 
txt1.grid(row=0,column=1)

lbl2 = Label(window, text="Second Number")
lbl2.grid(row=1,column=0)
txt2 = Entry(window,width=10)
txt2.grid(row=1,column=1)

lbl_sum=Label(window, text="Sum:")
lbl_sum.grid(row=2,column=0)

def clicked():
    res="Sum= "+str(float(txt1.get())+float(txt2.get()))
    lbl_sum.configure(text= res)

btn = Button(window, text="Compute", command=clicked)
btn.grid(row=3,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

This works perfectly fine in IDLE, but when run in Spyder, all I get a window with the correct title, "Sum Calculator" but nothing else (just white).

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? As an aside, using `import *` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding the use of *.

In terms of my environment, I'm not exactly sure what info is helpful, but I'm using a Mac running Catalina OS 10.15.4.

Spyder is running python 3.7, as is IDLE. However, there are two copies of python on my computer. Spyder is using one and IDLE the other. I've located the directory of each executable and described this issue in a separate post, which can be found at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395180/how-to-set-python-executable-path-in-idle?noredirect=1#comment108610409_61395180

Answer (score 0):

I updated to Spyder 4.1.2 and all works fine now.